# How to subtract values from one array of objects from another array of object using the same ID in REACT JS

Tags: reactjs, arrays, javascript-objects

I have two arrays of objects.
I'm trying to create a function that can subtract values from one array of objects from another array of object using the same id on name in REACT

```
export default function App() {
  const stockArray = [
    { id: 1, name: "Iphone", amount: 23 },
    { id: 2, name: "Samsung", amount: 28 },
    { id: 3, name: "Huawei", amount: 14 },
    { id: 4, name: "Motorola", amount:20 }
  ];

   const basketArray = [
    { id: 1, name: "Iphone", amount: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "Huawei", amount: 4 }
   ];

   const [stock, setStock] = React.useState(stockArray);
   const [basket, setBasket] = React.useState(basketArray);   

   const handleUpdateStock = () => {
    // How to subtract amount values in basketArray from amount values in stockArray
```

in objects   with the same id or name.

```
    // the result should be :

   // const stockArray = [
   //   { id: 1, name: "Iphone", amount: 20 },
   //   { id: 2, name: "Samsung", amount: 28 },
  //   { id: 3, name: "Huawei", amount: 10 },
  //   { id: 4, name: "Motorola", amount:20 }
  //  ];

   }
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Stock:</h3>
          {stock.map(product=> (
            <h5>{product.name} - {product.amount} </h5>
          ))}
      <br/>
      <h3>Basket:</h3>
          {basket.map(product=> (
            <h5>{product.name} - {product.amount} </h5>
          ))}
      <button onClick={handleUpdateStock}>Save and update stock </button>
    </div>

  );
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function substract (stockArray,basketArray){
  return stockArray.map(stock=>{
    const basket = basketArray.find(basket=>stock.id===basket.id);
      if(basket){
        return {
          ...stock,
          amount:stock.amount-basket.amount,
        }
      } else {
        return stock;
      }
 })
}
```

this function iterates all indexes in stockArray, will find same object with the same id in basketArray and if basket is an object, it changes value of amount in stock

Answer (score 1):

You can loop your stock array, and compare each product with in it with each product from the basket.

If they have the same id you should subtract the amount from the `product.amount` from the the product inside the basket.

In the end we should setStock with the new array.

```js
function App() {
  const stockArray = [
    { id: 1, name: "Iphone", amount: 23 },
    { id: 2, name: "Samsung", amount: 28 },
    { id: 3, name: "Huawei", amount: 14 },
    { id: 4, name: "Motorola", amount:20 }
    ];

  const basketArray = [
    { id: 1, name: "Iphone", amount: 3 },
    { id: 3, name: "Huawei", amount: 4 }
    ];

  const [stock, setStock] = React.useState(stockArray);
  const [basket, setBasket] = React.useState(basketArray);   

  const handleUpdateStock = () => {
    const newStock = stock.map(product => {
      const productInBasket = basket.find(el => el.id === product.id);
      
      if (!productInBasket) return product;
      
      return {
        ...product,
        amount: product.amount - productInBasket.amount,
      }
    })
    
    setStock(newStock);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Stock:</h3>
      {stock.map(product=> (
        <h5 key={product.id}>{product.name} - {product.amount} </h5>
      ))}
      <br/>
      <h3>Basket:</h3>
      {basket.map(product=> (
        <h5 key={product.id}>{product.name} - {product.amount} </h5>
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleUpdateStock}>Save and update stock </button>
    </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <App />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  It works perfectly.   I tried to resolve it with nested loops, but it looked awful.

Comment: Technically this has a nested loop too, it just isn't as clear as having a for inside a for. For instance, here we are iterating the 1st time using the map() and a 2nd time using the find()